# Direct labeling a line plot with Altair

Tags: python, python-3.x, altair

I'm plotting a line graph in Altair (4.1.0) and would like to use direct labeling (annotations) instead of a regular legend.
As such, the text mark for each line (say, time series) should appear only once and at the right-most point of the x-axis (as opposed to [this scatter plot example labeling every data point](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/scatter_with_labels.html)).
While I'm able to use pandas to manipulate the data to get the desired results, I think it would be more elegant to have a pure-Altair implementation, but I can't seem to get it right.

For example, given the following data:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

np.random.seed(10)
time = pd.date_range(start="10/21/2020", end="10/22/2020", periods=n)
data = pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame({
        "time": time,
        "group": "One",
        "value": np.random.normal(10, 2, n)}),
    pd.DataFrame({
        "time": time,
        "group": "Two",
        "value": np.random.normal(5, 2, n)}).iloc[:-1]
], ignore_index=True)
```

I can generate a satisfactory result using pandas to create a subset that includes the last time-point for each group:

```py
lines = alt.Chart(data).mark_line(
    point=True
).encode(
    x="time:T",
    y="value:Q",
    color=alt.Color("group:N", legend=None),  # Remove legend
)

text_data = data.loc[data.groupby('group')['time'].idxmax()]  # Subset the data for text positions
labels = alt.Chart(text_data).mark_text(
    # some adjustments
).encode(
    x="time:T",
    y="value:Q",
    color="group:N",
    text="group:N"
)

chart = lines + labels
```

[image]

However, if I try to use the main data and add Altair aggregations, for example using `x=max(time)` or explicit `transform_aggregate()`, I either get text annotations on all points or none at all (respectively).

Is there a better way to obtain the above result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using an `argmax` aggregate in the y encoding. For example, your labels layer might look like this:

```python
labels = alt.Chart(data).mark_text(
    align='left', dx=5
).encode(
    x='max(time):T',
    y=alt.Y('value:Q', aggregate={'argmax': 'time'}),
    text='group:N',
    color='group:N',
)
```

[image]

Comment: Ah ha! Aggregating the y according to x. this is new to me. May I ask why is it needed? (why was `x=max(time)` not sufficient?) and anyway, thanks a lot Jake, you're the best (and the fastest! :)

Comment: If you want a single text annotation per line, you need to define its x value and y value. You want the y value to be the one associated with the maximum x value, and the way to get that is using `argmax`. If you do `x='max(time)', y='value'` without aggregating value, you are specifying that you want a point per unique value, and within each set of unique values that point should be drawn at the maximum time. In terms of relational algebra, unaggregated columns are used as inputs to a group-by.